# Creating overlays with Prototype Javascript? Recommend a library or plugin?

Tags: html, overlay, prototypejs

Could you please recommend free Prototype libraries or plugins for the simple creation and management of web overlays?

We're using this one (http://kammerer.boo.pl/code/prototype-overlay/), but it seems to have trouble with forms (unless we're doing something wrong).

There are a ton of free ones for JQuery, but there seem to be very few free, high-quality ones for Prototype.  (Yes, yes, we need to eventually adopt JQuery.)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some HTML and JS? If you are having specific issues with the `<select>` element then you need to place an iFrame behind the modal, but it looks like that should already be handled from the link example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out we did something wrong with the overlay. The one we're using is still the best for Prototype (http://kammerer.boo.pl/code/prototype-overlay/), but we actually plan to migrate to jQuery eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific library for you but try looking for 'prototype modal' rather than overlay. Looks like there are a number of them.